# set_include_path() for subdirectories with CLI?

Tags: php, zend-framework, command-line-interface, autoload, include-path

I am using Zend Framework 1.11 in an application. I am trying to implement the [performance upgrade suggested by the manual](http://framework.zend.com/manual/en/performance.classloading.html) to eliminate needless require_once() statements and go full autoloading. This works fine in the normal application.

I also have a CLI interface I've coded for a daemon (via custom router in Bootstrap.php) which doesn't seem to want to play nice with my changes. It has to do with the include path I have setup, which is currently configured in my index.php ZF entry point:

```
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
   realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library/'),
   get_include_path(),
)));
```

The library folder is layed out like:

```
- library
   -Zend
      -Acl
      -Amf
       ... etc, Zend Framework files
   -Custom
      -Api
      -Twitter
       ... etc, My Custom library files
```

When running the application via CLI, it cannot find any files inside those directories or subdirectories. So I changed my include path to look like:

```
set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array(
   realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library/'),
   realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library/Custom/Twitter/'),
   get_include_path(),
)));
```

And then it is able to find the file I need.

**TL;DR;** I have a LOT of files in these libraries and any performance gain I may have gotten from autoloading will go out the window if I have to manually put each folder into the include path. Is there a better way?

P.S. On a whim I also tried a path like **/../library/*** but that doesn't work either.

Comment: Why can't the CLI script find the files with your previous setup? What error do you get?

Comment: `PHP Fatal error: Class 'Someclass' not found in /var/www/...` Rather than autoloading the class, it just fails. I found a temporary workaround where I only add the necessary paths inside of my CLI startup. That way the regular application isn't affected since it works as is. It's just a nuance that I'm not sure about the cause.

Comment: The error should include the paths it is checking (i.e. your include path) - so see if this looks right. You should definitely be able to get autoloading working the same way in your CLI app.

Comment: One thing to add, the CLI version of PHP has a separate php.ini file, and thus a separate include_path config option. If you are setting your include path up in php.ini you may need to do it in both places.

Comment: autoloading is slower compared to direct use of require_once .

Comment: One thing that immediately springs to mind is that you are mincing the original `include_path` with those calls. I think you'll find if you `echo get_include_path();` after the structures show above, it will say `/path/to/library/:/path/to/library/Custom/Twitter/:Array`. This is because you need to call `array_merge()`: `set_include_path(implode(PATH_SEPARATOR, array_merge(array(realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library/'),realpath(APPLICATION_PATH . '/../library/Custom/Twitter/')), get_include_path())));` (doesn't display well in a comment, get it in an editor)

Comment: Also don't forget that the working directory of the CLI script will (usually) be the working directory of the process that started it. If your script is looking for files relative to it's own location and was started by a process working in a different directory, that may be the cause (coupled with the fact that you destroyed the `.` entry in the `include_path`, see previous comment). Maybe it's worth doing `chdir(dirname(__FILE__));` at the top of your CLI script...

Comment: Thanks for the ideas guys. The working directory is the same via web or CLI. I use the index.php and check PHP_SAPI to determine if the request is coming from command line, and if so setup custom router and initialize ZF components I need. I'll give these suggestions a try when I get a few extra minutes.

Comment: Need to see the output of `echo getcwd();` `echo get_include_path();` and the content of the autoload function. And the line which has triggered the error.